# SonataAdmin custom route

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am trying to display different `Events` on a calendar in one of my SonataAdmin Entities.

I have 2 services, Practice and Event:

```
bm.user.admin.practice:
   class: BM\UserBundle\Admin\PracticeAdmin
   tags:
     - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: cvp_users, label: Practice }
   arguments: [bm.user.admin.practice, BM\UserBundle\Entity\Practice, BMUserBundle:PracticeAdmin]
```

and

```
bm.crm.admin.event:
   class: BM\CrmBundle\Admin\EventAdmin
   tags:
     - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: cvp_users, label: Schedule }
   arguments: [bm.crm.admin.event, BM\CrmBundle\Entity\Event, BMCrmBundle:EventAdmin]
```

The calendar is displayed in the `editAction` of the `Practice`

My problem is, I'm trying to get results from an action in the `EventAdminController`

```
/**
 * Fetch Events based on User.
 *
 * @Route("/admin-events-create/{id}", name="create_event", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method("GET|POST")
 * @Template()
 */
public function fetchEventsAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $em->getRepository('BMUserBundle:User')->find($id);
    $events = $em->getRepository('BMCrmBundle:Event')->findAllEventsByUser($user->getId());

}
```

I'm trying to call this using the following:

`{{ path('fetch_events', { _sonata_admin: 'bm.crm.admin.events'} ) }}`

But that is missing the `id` that I need to use in the controller.

Changing it to:

`{{ path('fetch_events', { id: 'myObj.id', _sonata_admin: 'bm.crm.admin.event'} ) }}` or anything similar always gives me:

`There is no`_sonata_admin`defined for the controller`

Any ideas on how I can pass the `id` value I need to the route?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in EventAdmin class

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
```

then add method

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->add('fetch_events', '{id}/fetch_events');
}
```

You can check declared routes for admin class if you are on *nix system with **grep**:

```
php app/console router:debug | grep events
```

use it as

```
{{ path('fetch_events', { 'id': object.id } ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is in path

```
{{ path('fetch_events', { 'id': object.id } ) }}
```

Sonata custom route is prefixed with base route name of admin:

```
{{ path('your_admin_base_route_name_fetch_events', { 'id': object.id } ) }}
```

short name of custom route can be used for URL generated by admin method

```
admin.generateUrl('fetch_events', { 'id': object.id } )
```